# How to fix ORDER BY with item ids?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table containing item id's
some examples are:

```
1
1:3
2:1
2:2
3
3:1
12:2
21:2
```

I want them to be sorted in the way listed ^
The MYSQL sorts them in following order:

```
1
1:3
12:2
2:1
2:2
21:2
3
3:1
```

Anyone has any idea how to fix that problem?

Comment: Is there a case of an id like `1:2:3`?

Comment: Nope, there are only X and X:Y cases.

Comment: And I want them to be sorted primarly by X and secondary by Y.

Comment: what is the max width of "x" or "y" is it always 1 or 2 chars width like `12:2` r are there also cases like `999:2`

Comment: Some examples ->1, 1:1, 1:441, 3:5123, 4:125, 125:432 (Max X length is 3, Max Y length is 5)

Comment: offtopic: also you would be better of storing this infromation in separated columns x and y instead of a varchar based column.

Comment: Finally, the voice of reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) it is possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnVal, ':', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnVal, ':', 2) AS UNSIGNED)
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41c514a8b850a05fc1f842af4d478099)

In another way using [`POSITION()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-position-function.php)

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ColumnVal, ':', 2) AS UNSIGNED),
         POSITION(":" IN ColumnVal),
         SUBSTRING(ColumnVal, POSITION(":" IN ColumnVal) + 1, LENGTH(ColumnVal))
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00f5738b9d5b71b9c58645ca2feacdb3)

Comment: The OP wants 12 near the end

Comment: The following puts 12:1 before 101 :z

Comment: Getting warmer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7d4e90eaa929555395a2603daf5ab06

Comment: Works properly, please rep that guy here <3 You made my day

Comment: @Szymek. In that case your specification is wrong. This result is different from what was requested: (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7d4e90eaa929555395a2603daf5ab06)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT _table.*
#      , RPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_table._col, ':', 1), 3, 0)
FROM
    (
     SELECT
         CAST('1' AS CHAR) AS _col
     UNION
     SELECT
         '1:3'
     UNION
     SELECT
         '2:1'
     UNION
     SELECT
         '2:2'
     UNION
     SELECT
         '3'
     UNION
     SELECT
         '3:1'
     UNION
     SELECT
         '12:2'
     UNION
     SELECT
         '21:2') _table
ORDER BY RPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_table._col, ':', 1), 3, 0),
    RPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_table._col, ':', 2), 5, 0)
;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use `ABS()` or `CAST()` if that satisfy you as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ABS(column);
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CAST(column as DECIMAL);
```

Comment: Both methods would result into a INT see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rNFZuMMfBVBAXNGymcMDYN/0)

Comment: @RaymondNijland that could be a way around. What's your solution? Please share with us.